# How may I use CRF in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, crf

In NLTK like HMM tagger, there seems to be CRF tagger also. But I am not finding any tutorial or help. How should I do it?

Answer (score 6):

Really really late answer on this one, but just in case you wanted to have an example, you can find one [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tpeng/python-crfsuite/blob/master/examples/CoNLL%202002.ipynb). Also note that this CRF interface is not an interface to [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/), but it is an interface to [CRFsuite](https://github.com/chokkan/crfsuite)

Comment: The latest commit dates on CRFsuite do seem to suggest some question marks though, at present time

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/crf.html), I gather that the CRF tagger in NLTK is just an interface for [Mallet's CRF](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/fst/CRF.html) implementation. So, I think this tutorial on using [Mallet's CRF](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/fst.php) might be helpful as it would give insight into the steps required to get CRF to work in Mallet and the NLTK module should proceed in the same way. I couldn't find any tutorial on NLTK-CRF, either

Comment: Are you sure it is based on Mallet? I might be a bit late to this, but I think the CRF tagger is actually an interface to [CRFsuite](https://github.com/chokkan/crfsuite)

Comment: @N00bsie used to be Mallet https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/104. "In #855 we are discussing the idea of using CRFSuite instead of Mallet. There seems to be no reason to provide a Mallet interface. Unless there are any objections, I propose that we provide a CRF tagger using CRFSuite." ; https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/855 : "We've agreed to use CRFSuite instead. The main advantage of Mallet is configurability, and this is not exposed via the NLTK wrapper. We prefer the faster speed of CRFSuite."

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.crf Here it clearly says that CRF tagger is an interface to CRFSuite.